# C# cannot convert to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to learn C# when I ran into the following error:

```
CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'BookAPI.Models.DbContextOPtions<BookAPI.Models.BookContext>' 
to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'
```

I'm just following the tutorial here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWJayOop4k8

I am creating the file called BookContext.cs.  As of right now, the code looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookAPI.Models
{
  public class BookContext : DbContext
  {
    public BookContext(DbContextOPtions<BookContext> options)
        :base(options) // <-- error is pointing here
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 free version on a Mac.

What am I missing and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public class BookContext : DbContext
  {
    public BookContext(DbContextOptions<BookContext> options)
        :base(options) 
    {
       ....
    }
  }
```

Comment: You mean to tell me this error was caused over a typo???

Comment: I should probably delete this question.

Comment: @JohnBeasley Yes

Comment: @JohnBeasley try it at first. I am sure you still have another typos

Comment: It worked.  Thank you. Should I delete this question, or accept your answer?

Comment: @JohnBeasley You are welcome. It is up to you. I would delete it

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo error in `DbContextOPtions` it should be `DbContextOptions`
if you want to copy the full code check the below

```
 public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) :base(options)
    {

    }
```